# Visual studio cannot discover tests (xunit)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, xunit

I have a problem with visual studio 2015 for Web while discovering tests. 
I wrote simple .Net core application, added project with test, my project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.3.1",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.3.1",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my test project i wrote first test:

```
using Xunit;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }

        [Fact]
        public void HelloWorld()
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I build solution my test is not discovered and I get this message in test output window:

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0475339) ==========
------ Discover test started ------
An exception occurred while test discoverer 'DotNetTestDiscoverer' was loading tests. Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0145118) ==========
```

And the funny thing is there isnt even Newtonsoft.Json with version 6.0.0.0.

I tried the following:

1. Change test architecture to x64
2. Start visual studio as administrator
3. Reopen VS
4. Delete %TEMP%/VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions folder
5. Create new project
6. Change both tests and project architecture to x86

Note:
When I run dotnet test it works fine, but I'd like to have my tests in tests window, because I cannot debug tests from the console.

Edit:
I've created repository causing the problem, feel free to look it up:
https://github.com/Rodeck/XunitIssue

Edit2:
Im using .netcore sdk version 1.0.0-preview2-003131.

Comment: The error says it can't find a specific version of `Newtonsoft.Json`. Are you using `Newtonsoft.Json` in your project?

Comment: No, I am not. I pasted my entire project.json.

Comment: But then you have a transient dependency from some other dependency. You need to fix that. Have you tried to install Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Yes I did, insalled newtonsoft.json 9.0.1 (xunit depends on it but no success). There is not Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0.0.0 but error indicates it.
Moreover this project (from repository) works on different computer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - xunit doesn't support visual studio 2015 express edition.